# Windows Phone - WCF- Error There was no endpoint listening at

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-phone-7, wcf-data-services

I am having an error when try to build the project. In my project, when the client send phone number to the service, serivce will return all infomation of user has this phone number.

this is service

```
      namespace ICService
{
    public class ProfileService : IProfileService
    {
        public lbl_Profile ViewProfile(int phonenumber)
        {
            Profileview profile = new Profileview();
            return profile.ViewProfile(phonenumber);
        }
    }

    public class Profileview 
    {
        public lbl_Profile ViewProfile(int phonenumber)
        {
            try
            {
                ToPiDataContext db = new ToPiDataContext();
                var query = (from m in db.lbl_Accounts
                             from n in db.lbl_Profiles
                             where m.AccountID == n.AccountID && m.Phonenumber == phonenumber
                             select new
                             {
                                 n.AccountID
                             }).First();

                var profile = (from m in db.lbl_Profiles
                              where m.AccountID == query.AccountID
                              select m).First();
                return profile;
            }
            catch
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

in the client

```
public partial class Profile : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
public Profile()
{
                InitializeComponent();
                   ProfileServiceClient profileClient = new ProfileServiceClient();
                profileClient.ViewProfileCompleted += new EventHandler<ViewProfileCompletedEventArgs>(profileService_ViewProfileCompleted);
                profileClient.ViewProfileAsync(phonenumber);
}

        void profileService_ViewProfileCompleted(object sender, ViewProfileCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
                txbFirstName.Text = e.Result.FirstName;
                txbLastName.Text = e.Result.LastName;
                txbLocation.Text = e.Result.Location;
                txbGenre.Text = e.Result.Genre;
        }
}
```

the config in web service

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

in the phone

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IAccountService" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
                maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
                <security mode="None" />
            </binding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IProfileService" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
                maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
                <security mode="None" />
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:2183/AccountService.svc"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IAccountService"
            contract="AccountService.IAccountService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IAccountService" />
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:2183/ProfileService.svc"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IProfileService"
            contract="ProfileService.IProfileService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IProfileService" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

and this is error 
[image: http://i915.photobucket.com/albums/ac358/thewall_trancong/Untitled-14.png]

Comment: **SHOW US THE CONFIG!!** Most of the relevant WCF stuff is defined in config - anything inside the `<system.serviceModel>` section - both on the server and the client - without it, we cannot possibly help

Comment: Thanks, I edited on my post. Can you help me to fix this ?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is down to what is localhost and which device you are on at the time.

On your development machine localhost is the development machine. On the phone it is the phone. When debugging the phone phone application on the development machine localhost is still the phone (however confusing that is).

Try changing to using IP addreses during development. e.g. 192.168.1.1 (or whatever your development PC is using). You can look this up using ipconfig on your dev machine.

Edit:

Change your config file to look like

```
<client>
    <endpoint address="http://192.168.1.1:2183/AccountService.svc"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IAccountService"
        contract="AccountService.IAccountService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IAccountService" />
    <endpoint address="http://192.168.1.1:2183/ProfileService.svc"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IProfileService"
        contract="ProfileService.IProfileService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IProfileService" />
</client>
```

Comment: I don't really understand your idea. Can you show me more detail?

Comment: the project has another service name AccountService. It returns infomation when users login or register. It really works. But this Profile Service does not work???

Comment: Are you sure that this Profile Service has the valid URL in your config file?  at **<endpoint address ="<profile service url here>" ... >**. If not, give a try

Comment: @ 4u.Ans:  of course, you can see it on the post. And the service is really work  http://i915.photobucket.com/albums/ac358/thewall_trancong/Untitled-15.png

Comment: @gbanfill: I tried but it still didn't work. I kept the ProfileService an changed all the code inside to return another value then it worked. So I think address is not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are pointing to a url that is not live yet. Try to use your local service or a service that is deployed on public space / domain.

I had same problem and got resolved when I started pointing it to local environment.

Comment: @ Shailesh Thanks to answer :) but the service is already live. I checked it on the web browsers. http://i915.photobucket.com/albums/ac358/thewall_trancong/Untitled-15.png

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for reading and answering my questions. I've just fixed it.The problem is in lbl_Profile(it is a table on database). I don't understand why it didn't work, but when I used List < string> to replaced lbl_Profile, it worked well.

int service

```
public List<string> profile(int phonenumber)
{
    ToPiDataContext db = new ToPiDataContext();
    var query = (from m in db.lbl_Accounts
                 from n in db.lbl_Profiles
                 where m.AccountID == n.AccountID && m.Phonenumber == phonenumber
                 select new
                 {
                     n.AccountID
                 }).First();

    var profile = (from m in db.lbl_Profiles
                   where m.AccountID == query.AccountID
                   select m).First();
    List<string> lst = new List<string>();
    lst.Add(profile.FirstName);
    lst.Add(profile.LastName);
    lst.Add(profile.Location);
    lst.Add(profile.Genre);
    return lst;

}
```

int client

```
void Profile_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
                int query = (from m in localaccount.account
                             select m.PhoneNumber).First();
                ProfileServiceClient profileClient = new ProfileServiceClient();
                profileClient.profileCompleted += new EventHandler<profileCompletedEventArgs>(profileClient_profileCompleted);
                profileClient.profileAsync(query);
            }

    void profileClient_profileCompleted(object sender, profileCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        txtFirstName.Text = e.Result[0];
        txtLastName.Text = e.Result[1];
        txtLocation.Text = e.Result[2];
        txbGenre.Text = e.Result[3];
    }
```